# Model with interaction completely different than without

Tags: regression, interaction

I have a regression model with 2 numeric independent variables and I set up a model without an interaction term. This is the result:

```
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.27443    0.76675   1.662    0.105    
Var1         1.00115    0.17742   5.643 1.76e-06 ***
Var2        -0.08345    0.10929  -0.764    0.450    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5374 on 38 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4815,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4542 
F-statistic: 17.65 on 2 and 38 DF,  p-value: 3.802e-06
```

The result is as expected. One positive and effect significant, the other not significant.
Then I tried the same model with an interaction term.
The result:

```
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)        7.0820     3.7597   1.884   0.0675 .
Var1              -0.2013     0.7823  -0.257   0.7983  
Var2              -1.6966     1.0288  -1.649   0.1076  
Var1:Var2          0.3300     0.2093   1.577   0.1234  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.5272 on 37 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.5142,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4748 
F-statistic: 13.05 on 3 and 37 DF,  p-value: 5.763e-06
```

The regression coefficients are completely different and I don't understand why.
I don't think there is an interaction effect and I expected almost the same model as the first and a (very) small coefficient for the interaction term. Do you have an idea why this is not the case?
I'm sorry I can't provide the data ...

This is the correlation between the variables:

```
                 Var1      Var2 Interaction Dependent
Var1        1.0000000 0.4321173   0.7010085 0.6881562
Var2        0.4321173 1.0000000   0.9425496 0.2169298
Interaction 0.7010085 0.9425496   1.0000000 0.4325696
Dependent   0.6881562 0.2169298   0.4325696 1.0000000
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth answering why you think the models should be similar.

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

With the introduction of the interaction term, you now have three terms that 'share' the correlation. What used to be the significant correlation of Var1 is now shared between Var1 and Var1:Var2, with the result that both correlations are now not significant anymore (and the coefficient for Var1 even flips from plus 1 to minus 0.2).

To better understand these results, I suggest to **run a univariate correlation** for all three terms independently, that is between Var1 and your dependent variable, between Var2 and your dependent variable, and between 'Var1:Var2' (that would be the product of Var1 and Var2, Var1 x Var2) and your dependent variable. That should give you a hint whether to include Var1:Var2 or not.

*(some additional thoughts added)*

- The fact that the coefficients of a three-variable LR look totally different from the coefficients of a two-variable LR does not mean that the Model itself 'is totally different' or renders totally different results. To check this, compare the residuals of your first model with those of the 2nd model (e.g., in a scatter plot).
- Also, if you don't have a 'subject matter' justification to include the interaction term, don't include it.
- Based on the univariate analysis, why not exclude Var2 and try a model with only Var1 and Var1:Var2?
- In the end, it is you who has to decide whether you want the mathematically best fit (e.g., the highest R² - but there are lot of other measures) - which may include counterintuitive negative coefficients -  ***or*** a model that can still be explained and where the coefficients 'make common sense'.
- Have you used the train data / test data concept to test your model? You need to avoid overfitting.

Comment: Thank you! I've added the correlation matrix to my question. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I have edited my response.